# How to get multimonitor remote desktop to work in win-server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I've tried to connect to my windows server 2008 R2 using Windows 7 and also I've checked the checkbox "use all monitors for the remote connection" (or what it was called), however it only shows up on one monitor, and I'm not shure what's wrong. Anyone got any solutions?

Comment: Should have been asked on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

Check the ["Limit maximum number of monitors per session"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx) setting in the Remote Desktop setup on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the run line, you need to type "mstsc /span".  It will allow you to use multiple monitors for your remote session.

Comment: /span is for win vista. Win7 supports the more powerfull /multimon-feature. But I can't get it to work.